# Expanding polynomials using valuation

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion

I would like to expand the polynomial $p(\lambda) = \sum_{i=0}^{d} a_{i} \lambda^{i}$, as $F(p(\lambda), \lambda_{0})= \min_{j} [ val(a_{j}) + j \lambda_{0} ] $ with $\lambda_{0}$ being a real variable. Here, $val(a)$ is the valuation, which is the lowest exponent of the non-zero Puiseux series.
The valuation satisfies
\begin{align}
val(a) =\infty \text{ iff } a=0 ,\quad
val(ab) =val(a)+val(b),\quad
val(a+b) \geq \min [ val(a) , val(b) ].
\end{align}
For example, $val(t^{2} -2t+3) = \min [ val(t^2) , val(-2t), val(3) ] =\min [ 2,1,0 ]=0$. The above suggested expansion for polynomial $p=\lambda^{2} - x^{2} -2x$ with respect to variable $\lambda$ reads $F(p(\lambda), \lambda_{0}) = \min[1, 2 \lambda_{0}]$.

For a simple polynomial, I have obtained the valuation using

```
poly = -2 x  + x^2 + 3
val = Min[Exponent[DeleteCases[MonomialList[poly], {0}], x]]
```

However, this fails when `MonomialList` has zero elements. I have excluded these cases using `DeleteCases` such that

```
poly = -2 x  - x^2 +  \[Lambda]^2
coeff = CoefficientList[poly, \[Lambda]]
val = Min @@@ Exponent[DeleteCases[MonomialList[coeff], {0}], x]
(*{1, 0}*)
```

The output `val` has components for $\lambda^{0}$ and $\lambda^{2}$ and $\lambda^{1}$ is the deleted case. To obtain $F$ for the particular example, I have used

```
F[i_, val_] := Min[val + i Subscript[\[Lambda], 0]];
F[{0, 2}, val ]
(*{1, 2 Subscript[\[Lambda], 0]}*)
```

Here, I have now explicitly passed to the function that $\ i \in \{0,2\}$ as $i=0$ was excluded.

Do you have any suggestions on better implementing these steps so that $F$ can be calculated more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
Min[CoefficientRules[#[[2]], x][[All, 1, 1]]] + #[[1, 
      1]] \[Lambda]0 & /@ CoefficientRules[poly, \[Lambda]]

(* {2 \[Lambda]0, 1} *)
```

Or:

```
MapIndexed[
 (# /. {
      0 -> Infinity,
      p_ :> Min[CoefficientRules[p, x][[All, 1, 1]]]
      }) + (First[#2] - 1) \[Lambda]0 &
 , CoefficientList[poly, \[Lambda]]
 ]

(* {1, \[Infinity], 2 \[Lambda]0} *)
```

You mentioned `Infinity` in the question, but maybe that was just a kludge for `Min`. I suppose each of the whole codes above should be wrapped in `Min` to the get capital `F` function in the first sentence. The OP didn't do it, so I was confused. Anyway, if I didn't do it right, I hope it gives you some ideas you can use!

P.S. I'd [avoid using subscripts in code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395) and reserve `Subscript` for formatting output. For instance, `Subscript[\[Lambda], 0]` is a function of `\[Lambda]` as an expression in Mathematica, and that is not how it should be treated in this problem. (Admittedly, it rarely causes problems, but it has caused them.)

Comment: (+1) Thank you for your suggestion on not using `Subscript` and also for your answer.

Comment: When I apply the first approach to `poly = \[Lambda]^2 + x^2 + y z` with $y$ and $z$ being other symbolic variables. I get `{2 \[Lambda]0, 0}` while I was expecting `{2 \[Lambda]0, 2} ` as valuation with respect to $x$ is 2.

Comment: @Shasa That's because `y z` as a polynomial in `x` is the degree 0 term.  So the minimum degree is 0.  What would you want if `poly = \[Lambda]^2 + x^2 + x y z`? Still 2, or 1? I'd guess 1. For instance, `CoefficientRules[x^2 + y z, {x, y, z}]` gives a rule for each ordered list of powers, `{2, 0, 0}` and `{0, 1, 1}`. Should we discard any list of powers beginning with zero, say `{0, b, c}` where b or c is not zero? Except keep `{0, 0, 0}` if there is a  numeric constant term, as in `CoefficientRules[x^2 + y z + 3, {x, y, z}]`?

Comment: you are correct regarding my concern. For my list of polynomials, the constants do not appear usually. So, no specific care should be given to that.